# Equivalence relation help

Tags: equivalence-relations

If $|A| = 30$ and the equivalence relation $R$ on $A$ partitions $A$ into (disjoint) equivalence classes $A_1$, $A_2$, and $A_3$, where $|A_1| = |A_2| = |A_3|$, then what is $|R|$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $R = A_1 \times A_1 \cup A_2 \times A_2 \cup A_3 \times A_3$, so $|R|=|A_1\times A_1|+|A_2\times A_2|+|A_3\times A_3|$.

Comment: Thanks.. you've helped a lot.

Comment: @DaleBryant: You should vote up (up-arrow) answers you like. If one of them really does it for you, click the check mark to accept it.

Comment: It says I need more reputation to vote up..

Comment: @Dale: You will need $15$ reputation to be able to vote up, but then you'll be able to vote up to $40$ times per day. Welcome to the StackExchange!

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
$$
R =
\{(x_1,y_1):x_1,y_1\in A_1\}
\cup
\{(x_2,y_2):x_2,y_2\in A_2\}
\cup
\{(x_3,y_3):x_3,y_3\in A_3\}.
$$

Count each of these separately, then add.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: Note that for $j=1,2,3$, and any $x,y\in A_j,$ we have $(x,y)\in R.$ That means that $A_j\times A_j\subseteq R$ for $j=1,2,3$. In fact (why?), $$R=\bigcup_{j=1}^3A_j\times A_j,$$ and this union is disjoint. Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yup.. thanks so much.